# MS Sql Server Triggers (2) executing at the same time: How do I catch what's causing it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, datatrigger

So I have 2 triggers on a table in my dbase. It's purpose is to log any data manipulation activities done by the user or by a third party import/export. The table where it saves it to have a datestamp which obviously marks when it was executed. For some reason, when this third party SSIS package writes a record to it it would trigger the triggers (as expected) but will have the exact same time. 1 record for inserting the record, and another record for updating the record. The problem is the datestamp is exactly the same up to the millisecond.

Any ideas on how I can track the cause of this? Should I be looking at the SSIS package? I dont think that would cause the 2 triggers tho.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why is the same datestamp a problem?  To see the actual order add a timestamp column to the audit table.

Comment: Hmm.. I dont understand your question. I already have the datastamp on my table(where the trigger writes the action). It writes an insert and an update on this instance with the same instance. We need it for reporting on which is the latest action executed.

Comment: @gdubs - `TIMESTAMP` is a misnomer, it provides a value guaranteed to be unique in the database, not a date or time.  Just what you want.  [`ROWVERSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.100).aspx) is an alternative and more fitting name.

Comment: Uh, clearly the insert came before the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using SQL profiler to see what is being called. But my suspicion would be SSIS.

Comment: There was something wrong with the SSIS. It was made by a third party, didn't thought of checking it. had to ask them what changes were made that may have caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server the DATETIME data type has a resolution of 3 milliseconds. While that sounds short, it is enough time for several thousand instructions to execute on a modern CPU. So if an insert is directly followed by an update there is a high chance for them to endup with the same DATETIME value.

You could increase the resolution to 100 nanoseconds by using a DATETIME2 data type and the SYSDATETIME() function to value it. But even with that you might end up with duplicate values.

The easiest way to get the order of execution is to add an IDENTITY column to the log table. From it's ever increasing value you can directly discern the order.

Comment: As the note for [`SYSDATETIME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353.aspx) says, the precision is 100ns but the accuracy may vary.  A typical accuracy is 15ms making `DATETIME` more precise than the system clock.